# GAE ImagesServiceFactory Composite not honoring PNG transparency

Tags: google-app-engine

The code for image compositing in Google App Enginee doesn't appear to honor a PNGs 
transparency. Has anyone been able to successfully composite a 
transparent png over another image in the latest version of the SDK 
(1.6.1). I've seen a post that discussed compositing in GWT but I can already
composite in HTML5 (canvas) so that's not useful. See
http://groups.google.com/group/google-appengine-java/browse_thread/th... 
where the solution was to incorporate a GWT canvas.

I have something along the lines of,

`

```
Image image = null;

List<Composite> composites = new ArrayList<Composite>(); 

Iterator<ImageObj> iterator = images.iterator(); 

while (iterator.hasNext()) { 
    ImageObj io = (ImageObj)iterator.next(); 
    //returns an Image 
    image = io.getImage(someWidth, someHeight); 
    composites.add(ImagesServiceFactory.makeComposite(image, io.x, io.y, 1.0f, Composite.Anchor.TOP_LEFT)); 
}
```

Image = ImagesServiceFactory.getImagesService().composite(composites, 
width, height, 0); `

Where some images are JPEGs and some are PNGs with transparency.

So, compositing works fine but the png transparency is not honored.

Note - Since several of these images are in the 750K 
range, I need to composite them on the server and reduce the 
bandwidth of sending multiple images over http.

Can anyone comment on this assumption. 
1) Is the speed of GAE compositing multiple 1M images and downloading 
a single image compared to downloading those same multiple images to 
the browser much faster? 
2) Is the GAE cost of CPU for compositing comparable to GAE cost for 
bandwidth?

Comment: Would be great if you could add a link to a specific issue in the issue tracker (http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/list).

Answer (score 2):

**Sample Code**:
The Java and Python examples below utilize the images API as follows. We take a PNG image with an alpha channel (i.e. parts of the image are transparent) to create a composite image where the original image is overlaid on top of itself, offset by half its width.

> [image: sample image]
>
> **Note**:
> Emulation of the Images API in the dev_appserver is incomplete. Not all features, such as transparency / opacity, are [properly implemented](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=8364) in the SDK. However, the below examples were all tested and work in the production App Engine environment.

***Java + Images API:***

```
package img;

import com.google.appengine.api.images.Composite;
import com.google.appengine.api.images.Image;
import com.google.appengine.api.images.ImagesService;
import com.google.appengine.api.images.ImagesServiceFactory;
import com.google.appengine.api.images.Transform;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.RandomAccessFile;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collection;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class ImgServlet extends HttpServlet {

  @Override
  public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
      throws IOException {
    RandomAccessFile file = new RandomAccessFile("image.png", "r");
    byte[] data = new byte[(int) file.length()];
    file.read(data);
    file.close();

    ImagesService imagesService = ImagesServiceFactory.getImagesService();

    Image image = ImagesServiceFactory.makeImage(data);
    Transform resize = ImagesServiceFactory.makeResize(50, 50);

    image = imagesService.applyTransform(resize, image);

    Composite composite1 =
        ImagesServiceFactory.makeComposite(image, 0, 0, 1.0F,
                                           Composite.Anchor.TOP_LEFT);
    Composite composite2 =
        ImagesServiceFactory.makeComposite(image, 25, 0, 1.0F,
                                           Composite.Anchor.TOP_LEFT);
    Collection<Composite> composites =
        Arrays.asList(new Composite[] {composite1, composite2});

    image = imagesService.composite(
        composites, 75, 50, 0, ImagesService.OutputEncoding.PNG);

    data = image.getImageData();

    resp.setContentType("image/png");
    resp.getOutputStream().write(data);
  }
}
```

***Python 2.7 + Images API:***

```
import webapp2
from google.appengine.api import images
  
class MainHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):

  def get(self):
    img = images.Image(open("image.png").read())
    img.resize(50, 50)
    result = img.execute_transforms(output_encoding=images.PNG)
    t1 = (result, 0, 0, 1.0, images.TOP_LEFT)
    t2 = (result, 25, 0, 1.0, images.TOP_LEFT)
    result = images.composite([t1, t2], 75, 50, color=0,
                              output_encoding=images.PNG, quality=None)
    self.response.headers['content-type'] = 'image/png'
    self.response.write(result)

app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
  ('/.*', MainHandler),
], debug=True)
```

***Python 2.7 + PIL:***

An alternative python27 solution is to use the [PIL library](http://www.pythonware.com/library/pil/handbook/), available as a supported [python27 third-party library](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/libraries27).

```
import webapp2
from StringIO import StringIO
from PIL import Image

class MainHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):

  def get(self):
    image1 = Image.open("image1.png")
    image2 = Image.open("image2.png")
    image = Image.composite(image1, image2, image1)
    result = StringIO()
    image.save(result, "PNG")
    self.response.headers['content-type'] = 'image/png'
    self.response.write(result.getvalue())

app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
  ('/.*', MainHandler),
], debug=True)
```